# Unity GetRootGameObjects returns empty array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the hierarchy of game objects in a scene in Unity (version 2022.1.24), starting by calling GetRootGameObjects. However this method returns an empty array. To test this I have the following code:

```
class Overlay : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnGUI()
    {
        string text = $"{SceneManager.GetActiveScene().GetRootGameObjects().Length}";
        GUI.Box(new Rect(10, 10, Screen.width - 20, 20), text);
    }
}
```

Sure enough it displays 0. The scene loads fine and the game objects are all there and working properly, but they don't show up when I call GetRootGameObjects. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I know not directly an answer to your issue in specific

But this is what I happen to have lying around ^^

```
private const float k_LineHeight = 18f;
private const float k_Indent = 10f;

[SerializeField] private Texture2D m_SceneIcon;
[SerializeField] private Texture2D m_ObjectIcon;

private Vector2 m_Scroll;

private void OnGUI()
{
    var sceneInfos = new List<SceneInfo>();
    var lines = 0;

    var sceneCount = SceneManager.sceneCount;
    for (var i = 0; i < sceneCount; i++)
    {
        var scene = SceneManager.GetSceneAt(i);
        var sceneInfo = new SceneInfo(scene, m_SceneIcon, m_ObjectIcon);

        lines += sceneInfo.GetLines();

        sceneInfos.Add(sceneInfo);
    }

    var position = new Rect(10, 10, Screen.width - 20, Screen.height - 20);
    var innerRect = new Rect(0, 0, position.width, k_LineHeight * lines);

    using (new GUI.ScrollViewScope(position, m_Scroll, innerRect))
    {
        var y = 0f;

        foreach (var sceneInfo in sceneInfos)
        {
            sceneInfo.Draw(0, innerRect.width, ref y);
        }
    }
}

private abstract class Info<T> : IEquatable<Info<T>>
{
    private readonly GameObjectInfo[] m_Children;
    private readonly Texture m_Icon;
    private readonly Func<T, bool> m_IsFolded;
    private readonly string m_Name;

    private readonly T m_Obj;
    private readonly Action<T, bool> m_SetFolded;

    protected Info(T obj, string name, Texture icon, GameObjectInfo[] children, Func<T, bool> isFolded, Action<T, bool> setFolded)
    {
        m_Obj = obj;
        m_Name = name;
        m_Icon = icon;
        m_Children = children;
        m_IsFolded = isFolded;
        m_SetFolded = setFolded;
    }

    public bool Equals(Info<T> other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(m_Obj, other.m_Obj);
    }

    private void DrawLabel(Rect rect, bool isFolded)
    {
        var style = GUI.skin.label;

        if (m_Children.Length == 0)
        {
            GUI.Label(rect, new GUIContent(m_Name, m_Icon), style);
        }
        else
        {
            if (GUI.Button(rect, new GUIContent($"{(isFolded ? ">" : "v")} {m_Name}{(isFolded ? $" [+{GetNestedChildCount()}]" : string.Empty)}", m_Icon), style))
            {
                ToggleFolded();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw(int indentLevel, float viewportWidth, ref float y)
    {
        var isFolded = m_IsFolded(m_Obj);
        var rect = new Rect(indentLevel * k_Indent, y, viewportWidth - indentLevel * k_Indent, k_LineHeight);

        DrawLabel(rect, isFolded);

        y += k_LineHeight;

        if (isFolded)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var rootObject in m_Children)
        {
            rootObject.Draw(indentLevel + 1, viewportWidth, ref y);
        }
    }

    private void ToggleFolded()
    {
        m_SetFolded(m_Obj, !m_IsFolded(m_Obj));
    }

    public int GetLines()
    {
        if (m_IsFolded(m_Obj))
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return 1 + m_Children.Sum(rootObject => rootObject.GetLines());
    }

    private int GetNestedChildCount()
    {
        return m_Children.Length + m_Children.Sum(r => r.GetNestedChildCount());
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj.GetType() != GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Equals((Info<T>)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.GetHashCode(m_Obj);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Info<T> left, Info<T> right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Info<T> left, Info<T> right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}

private class SceneInfo : Info<Scene>
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Scene, bool> k_SceneFolded = new Dictionary<Scene, bool>();

    public SceneInfo(Scene scene, Texture sceneIcon, Texture objIcon)
        : base(scene, scene.name, sceneIcon, scene.GetRootGameObjects().Select(r => new GameObjectInfo(r, objIcon)).ToArray(), IsFolded, SetFolded) { }

    private static void SetFolded(Scene scene, bool folded)
    {
        k_SceneFolded[scene] = folded;
    }

    private static bool IsFolded(Scene scene)
    {
        if (!k_SceneFolded.ContainsKey(scene))
        {
            k_SceneFolded[scene] = true;
        }

        return k_SceneFolded[scene];
    }
}

private class GameObjectInfo : Info<GameObject>
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<GameObject, bool> k_ObjectFolded = new Dictionary<GameObject, bool>();

    public GameObjectInfo(GameObject gameObject, Texture icon)
        : base(gameObject, gameObject.name, icon, gameObject.transform.Cast<Transform>().Select(child => new GameObjectInfo(child.gameObject, icon)).ToArray(), IsFolded, SetFolded) { }

    private static void SetFolded(GameObject gameObject, bool folded)
    {
        k_ObjectFolded[gameObject] = folded;
    }

    private static bool IsFolded(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        if (!k_ObjectFolded.ContainsKey(gameObject))
        {
            k_ObjectFolded[gameObject] = true;
        }

        return k_ObjectFolded[gameObject];
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]